# Calculate difference between two numbers and get the absolute value

Tags: go, difference

I want to find the difference between two numbers in Go and the result should not be in "-".

Please find my code below:

```
    dollarValue := 240000 - 480000
```

The result is "-240000". But my expected output is just "240000". Can anybody help on how to calculate the difference between these two numbers.

Comment: Your title doesn't match the question at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your title is misleading. It should be states without `negative` instead of `- operator`.

Basically what you want to get is the absolute different between two numbers

You have two options:

- Use if/else condition to return the positive result if the result is negative
- Use [`math.Abs`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Abs) (need to convert from/to float)

Comment: Thank you @Manh.  math.abs worked for  me.

Answer (score 3):

Just implement your own method

```golang
func diff(a, b int) int {
   if a < b {
      return b - a
   }
   return a - b
}
```

and use it like this:

```
dollarValue := diff(240000, 480000)
```